# Linker errors in pcp_main example from libjingle

Tags: visual-studio, linker, libjingle

I'm working to get libjingle working on windows7 using visual studio. I followed GYP methodology to build lib jingle and got libs after executing the libjingle.sln file.

Now, when I'm trying to run pcp_main.cc file, I got slashed with linker errors, after some work around, I was left with 5 linker errors. Can someone help me how to resolve those errors?

> Error 5   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\PCPTest\Debug\PCPTest.exe Error 3   error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __thiscall
>   buzz::JingleInfoTask::HandleStanza(class buzz::XmlElement const *)"
>   (?HandleStanza@JingleInfoTask@buzz@@MAE_NPBVXmlElement@2@@Z)  C:\Users\username\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\PCPTest\PCPTest\pcp_main.obj
>
> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int
>   __thiscall buzz::JingleInfoTask::ProcessStart(void)" (?ProcessStart@JingleInfoTask@buzz@@UAEHXZ)  C:\Users\username\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\PCPTest\PCPTest\pcp_main.obj
>
> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall buzz::JingleInfoTask::RefreshJingleInfoNow(void)" (?RefreshJingleInfoNow@JingleInfoTask@buzz@@QAEXXZ) referenced in
>   function "public: void __thiscall
>   AutoPortAllocator::SetXmppClient(class buzz::XmppClient *)"
>   (?SetXmppClient@AutoPortAllocator@@QAEXPAVXmppClient@buzz@@@Z)    C:\Users\username\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\PCPTest\PCPTest\pcp_main.obj
>
> Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_InternetQueryOptionW@16 referenced in function "bool __cdecl talk_base::GetIeLanProxySettings(char const *,struct
>   talk_base::ProxyInfo *)"
>   (?GetIeLanProxySettings@talk_base@@YA_NPBDPAUProxyInfo@1@@Z)  C:\Users\username\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\PCPTest\PCPTest\libjingle.lib(proxydetect.obj)

My include folder is pointing to

> C:\Users\username\Desktop\libjingle\trunk\testing
>   C:\Users\username\Desktop\libjingle\trunk\

and lib folder to

> C:\Users\username\Desktop\libjingle\trunk\build\Debug\lib

Additional dependencies have absolute paths of all the available libs.

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\libjingle\trunk\build\Debug\lib\audio_processing_sse2.lib
C:\Users\username\Desktop\libjingle\trunk\build\Debug\lib\bitrate_controller.lib
C:\Users\username\Desktop\libjingle\trunk\build\Debug\lib\CNG.lib

... 
... 
...
```

The source codeI'm using is present here.

http://pastebin.com/GATFYWnW

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer!

The Error 4 can be removed by adding the following line

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")
```

The remaining errors correspond to the jingleInfoTask.cc and JingleInfotask.h files. Its a bit surprise to see that the solution file (libjingle.sln) doesnt have these files when it built libraries. The work around would be to add the jingleinfotask.cc and jingleinfotask.h files into xmpp folder and re-build the libjingle.sln file.

This will produce the jingleinfotask.obj and required lib files. Make sure you point the generated lib file in the additional dependencies section in linker section of project properties.